# Alternate solution for Nested 'For' loop

Tags: java

```
for(OPV=230;OPV<245;OPV++)
{   
   for(IKW = 1.3; IKW <= 2.9; IKW += 0.1)
   {
      for(OKW = 0.01; OKW < 0.50; OKW += 0.01)
      {
         for(OPI = 0.05; OPI < 1.10; OPI += 0.01)
         {
           System.out.println( OPV+" "+IKW+" "+OKW+" "+OPI"")   
         }
      }
  }
}
```

I want to print these data together but I don't want to use nested for loops its creating problem and I am not even getting the range of data which I have given in a loop. Is there any solution rather than nested for loop. Please suggest me.
@Andreas you can see the loop is going infinite i dont want that i want the following output:

```
OPV   IKW OKW   OPI
230, 1.3, 0.01, 0.05
231, 1.4, 0.02, 0.06 
232, 1.5, 0.03, 0.07 
233, 1.6, 0.04, 0.08
```

after the range will complete one's then it should repeat again 
private static final int RECORD_COUNT =5;
  I want it should be increase as my record_count will .
Example if i have entered recor_count =5 it should display only 5 records and it should be cumulative

Comment: What is an example of the data you do expect to get?

Comment: Note that your names are not consistent.

Comment: Actually there are total 9 for loops conditions for different variables so i don't want for all 9 variables to use nested for loop so i have to use all variable in nested for loop so that i can get all the data together but i am not getting the exact range data because of this nested loop. is there another solution  for nested for loop?

Comment: are you sure you dont want separator (like space or some special character) between your variables when you print them out.

Comment: @Pooja, please provide an example of your expected output. Right now, you are generating 4 columns, which increases from the OPI, to the OKW, to the IKW, to the OPV. Very easy to see if you change to use, e.g., `System.out.printf("%d\t%4.2f\t%4.2f\t%4.2f%n", OPV, IKW, OKW, OPI);`

Comment: How are you not getting the range of data? It would seem you are. See [this IDEONE of your code](https://ideone.com/jkDfuR). If you are talking about the rounding issue out at the 15th digit, that is to be expected from any `double` logic, and can be alleviated by following the advise by @KevinO to print to 2 decimals only. --- Anything other than independent loops will not give you all the combinations you want, so there is no other solution for that.

Comment: Edited: Output should be like this:
    OPV    IKW     OKW     OPI
    230   1.30     0.01    0.05
    
    till
    245    2.9     0.50     1.10
    
    then again it should start from the same range

Comment: @Andreas you can see the loop is going infinite i dont want that i want the following output: 230, 1.3, 0.01, 0.05
230, 1.3, 0.01, 0.05
231, 1.4, 0.02, 0.06
232, 1.5, 0.03, 0.07
233, 1.6, 0.04, 0.08
after the range will complete one's then it shoul repeat again

Comment: `[230;245[` by `1` is 15 values. `[1.3;2.9]` by `0.1` is 17 values. `[0.01;0.50[` by `0.01` is 49 values. `[0.05;1.10[` by `0.01` is 105 values. 15 * 17 * 49 * 105 = 1311975 combination, so you will get 1.3 million lines printed, which is not an infinite loop, just a very large one. If that is not what you want, then what do you want?

Comment: @Pooja Don't show what you expect in a comment where it is unreadable. Edit the question for all to see, in a nice formatted way.

Comment: With your updated question, where all values increment at the same time, when should it stop? The 4 values don't have the same cycle length (15 vs 17 vs 49 vs 105), so how many iterations do you want?

Comment: @Andreas please check the edited output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    int    OPV = 230  + i %  15;        // 230 - 244 by 1
    double IKW = 1.3  + i %  17 * 0.1;  // 1.3 - 2.9 by 0.1
    double OKW = 0.01 + i %  49 * 0.01; // 0.01 - 0.49 by 0.01
    double OPI = 0.05 + i % 105 * 0.01; // 0.05 - 1.09 by 0.01
    System.out.printf("%d, %.1f, %.2f, %.2f%n", OPV, IKW, OKW, OPI);
}
```

See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/riqozg) for running example.

**OUTPUT**

```
230, 1.3, 0.01, 0.05
231, 1.4, 0.02, 0.06
232, 1.5, 0.03, 0.07
233, 1.6, 0.04, 0.08
234, 1.7, 0.05, 0.09
235, 1.8, 0.06, 0.10
236, 1.9, 0.07, 0.11
237, 2.0, 0.08, 0.12
238, 2.1, 0.09, 0.13
239, 2.2, 0.10, 0.14
240, 2.3, 0.11, 0.15
241, 2.4, 0.12, 0.16
242, 2.5, 0.13, 0.17
243, 2.6, 0.14, 0.18
244, 2.7, 0.15, 0.19
230, 2.8, 0.16, 0.20
231, 2.9, 0.17, 0.21
232, 1.3, 0.18, 0.22
233, 1.4, 0.19, 0.23
234, 1.5, 0.20, 0.24
235, 1.6, 0.21, 0.25
236, 1.7, 0.22, 0.26
237, 1.8, 0.23, 0.27
238, 1.9, 0.24, 0.28
239, 2.0, 0.25, 0.29
240, 2.1, 0.26, 0.30
241, 2.2, 0.27, 0.31
242, 2.3, 0.28, 0.32
243, 2.4, 0.29, 0.33
244, 2.5, 0.30, 0.34
230, 2.6, 0.31, 0.35
231, 2.7, 0.32, 0.36
232, 2.8, 0.33, 0.37
233, 2.9, 0.34, 0.38
234, 1.3, 0.35, 0.39
235, 1.4, 0.36, 0.40
236, 1.5, 0.37, 0.41
237, 1.6, 0.38, 0.42
238, 1.7, 0.39, 0.43
239, 1.8, 0.40, 0.44
240, 1.9, 0.41, 0.45
241, 2.0, 0.42, 0.46
242, 2.1, 0.43, 0.47
243, 2.2, 0.44, 0.48
244, 2.3, 0.45, 0.49
230, 2.4, 0.46, 0.50
231, 2.5, 0.47, 0.51
232, 2.6, 0.48, 0.52
233, 2.7, 0.49, 0.53
234, 2.8, 0.01, 0.54
235, 2.9, 0.02, 0.55
236, 1.3, 0.03, 0.56
237, 1.4, 0.04, 0.57
238, 1.5, 0.05, 0.58
239, 1.6, 0.06, 0.59
240, 1.7, 0.07, 0.60
241, 1.8, 0.08, 0.61
242, 1.9, 0.09, 0.62
243, 2.0, 0.10, 0.63
244, 2.1, 0.11, 0.64
230, 2.2, 0.12, 0.65
231, 2.3, 0.13, 0.66
232, 2.4, 0.14, 0.67
233, 2.5, 0.15, 0.68
234, 2.6, 0.16, 0.69
235, 2.7, 0.17, 0.70
236, 2.8, 0.18, 0.71
237, 2.9, 0.19, 0.72
238, 1.3, 0.20, 0.73
239, 1.4, 0.21, 0.74
240, 1.5, 0.22, 0.75
241, 1.6, 0.23, 0.76
242, 1.7, 0.24, 0.77
243, 1.8, 0.25, 0.78
244, 1.9, 0.26, 0.79
230, 2.0, 0.27, 0.80
231, 2.1, 0.28, 0.81
232, 2.2, 0.29, 0.82
233, 2.3, 0.30, 0.83
234, 2.4, 0.31, 0.84
235, 2.5, 0.32, 0.85
236, 2.6, 0.33, 0.86
237, 2.7, 0.34, 0.87
238, 2.8, 0.35, 0.88
239, 2.9, 0.36, 0.89
240, 1.3, 0.37, 0.90
241, 1.4, 0.38, 0.91
242, 1.5, 0.39, 0.92
243, 1.6, 0.40, 0.93
244, 1.7, 0.41, 0.94
230, 1.8, 0.42, 0.95
231, 1.9, 0.43, 0.96
232, 2.0, 0.44, 0.97
233, 2.1, 0.45, 0.98
234, 2.2, 0.46, 0.99
235, 2.3, 0.47, 1.00
236, 2.4, 0.48, 1.01
237, 2.5, 0.49, 1.02
238, 2.6, 0.01, 1.03
239, 2.7, 0.02, 1.04
240, 2.8, 0.03, 1.05
241, 2.9, 0.04, 1.06
242, 1.3, 0.05, 1.07
243, 1.4, 0.06, 1.08
244, 1.5, 0.07, 1.09
230, 1.6, 0.08, 0.05
231, 1.7, 0.09, 0.06
232, 1.8, 0.10, 0.07
233, 1.9, 0.11, 0.08
234, 2.0, 0.12, 0.09
235, 2.1, 0.13, 0.10
236, 2.2, 0.14, 0.11
237, 2.3, 0.15, 0.12
238, 2.4, 0.16, 0.13
239, 2.5, 0.17, 0.14
240, 2.6, 0.18, 0.15
241, 2.7, 0.19, 0.16
242, 2.8, 0.20, 0.17
243, 2.9, 0.21, 0.18
244, 1.3, 0.22, 0.19
230, 1.4, 0.23, 0.20
231, 1.5, 0.24, 0.21
232, 1.6, 0.25, 0.22
233, 1.7, 0.26, 0.23
234, 1.8, 0.27, 0.24
235, 1.9, 0.28, 0.25
236, 2.0, 0.29, 0.26
237, 2.1, 0.30, 0.27
238, 2.2, 0.31, 0.28
239, 2.3, 0.32, 0.29
240, 2.4, 0.33, 0.30
241, 2.5, 0.34, 0.31
242, 2.6, 0.35, 0.32
243, 2.7, 0.36, 0.33
244, 2.8, 0.37, 0.34
230, 2.9, 0.38, 0.35
231, 1.3, 0.39, 0.36
232, 1.4, 0.40, 0.37
233, 1.5, 0.41, 0.38
234, 1.6, 0.42, 0.39
235, 1.7, 0.43, 0.40
236, 1.8, 0.44, 0.41
237, 1.9, 0.45, 0.42
238, 2.0, 0.46, 0.43
239, 2.1, 0.47, 0.44
240, 2.2, 0.48, 0.45
241, 2.3, 0.49, 0.46
242, 2.4, 0.01, 0.47
243, 2.5, 0.02, 0.48
244, 2.6, 0.03, 0.49
230, 2.7, 0.04, 0.50
231, 2.8, 0.05, 0.51
232, 2.9, 0.06, 0.52
233, 1.3, 0.07, 0.53
234, 1.4, 0.08, 0.54
235, 1.5, 0.09, 0.55
236, 1.6, 0.10, 0.56
237, 1.7, 0.11, 0.57
238, 1.8, 0.12, 0.58
239, 1.9, 0.13, 0.59
240, 2.0, 0.14, 0.60
241, 2.1, 0.15, 0.61
242, 2.2, 0.16, 0.62
243, 2.3, 0.17, 0.63
244, 2.4, 0.18, 0.64
230, 2.5, 0.19, 0.65
231, 2.6, 0.20, 0.66
232, 2.7, 0.21, 0.67
233, 2.8, 0.22, 0.68
234, 2.9, 0.23, 0.69
235, 1.3, 0.24, 0.70
236, 1.4, 0.25, 0.71
237, 1.5, 0.26, 0.72
238, 1.6, 0.27, 0.73
239, 1.7, 0.28, 0.74
240, 1.8, 0.29, 0.75
241, 1.9, 0.30, 0.76
242, 2.0, 0.31, 0.77
243, 2.1, 0.32, 0.78
244, 2.2, 0.33, 0.79
230, 2.3, 0.34, 0.80
231, 2.4, 0.35, 0.81
232, 2.5, 0.36, 0.82
233, 2.6, 0.37, 0.83
234, 2.7, 0.38, 0.84
235, 2.8, 0.39, 0.85
236, 2.9, 0.40, 0.86
237, 1.3, 0.41, 0.87
238, 1.4, 0.42, 0.88
239, 1.5, 0.43, 0.89
240, 1.6, 0.44, 0.90
241, 1.7, 0.45, 0.91
242, 1.8, 0.46, 0.92
243, 1.9, 0.47, 0.93
244, 2.0, 0.48, 0.94
230, 2.1, 0.49, 0.95
231, 2.2, 0.01, 0.96
232, 2.3, 0.02, 0.97
233, 2.4, 0.03, 0.98
234, 2.5, 0.04, 0.99
```

Answer (score 0):

A pseudo-code solution would be like this, note no nested loop is present as you requested:

```
// populate data structure
List<StringBuffer> list = new LinkedList<>();
loop as you want{// your OPV for
    list.add(what you want);
}
int i = 0;
loop as you want{// your IKW for
    StringBuffer s;
    if (i < list.size()){
     s = list.get(i);
     s.append(what you want);
     list.set(i, s);
    }
    else{
        s = new StringBuffer(what you want);
        list.add(s);
    }
    i++;
}
i = 0;
loop as you want{// your OKW for
    StringBuffer s;
    if (i < list.size()){
     s = list.get(i);
     s.append(what you want);
     list.set(i, s);
    }
    else{
        s = new StringBuffer(what you want);
        list.add(s);
    }
    i++;
}
i = 0;
loop as you want{// your OPI for
    StringBuffer s;
    if (i < list.size()){
     s = list.get(i);
     s.append(what you want);
     list.set(i, s);
    }
    else{
        s = new StringBuffer(what you want);
        list.add(s);
    }
    i++;
}
// print data structure
for (StringBuffer s: list)
    System.out.println(s.toString());
```